# Using str_replace to replace {name} with the persons name

Tags: mysql, email, str-replace

I am using the following code to try and get the persons name which is held in $name and changing the {name} field in the email body array $body with the persons name held in the $name value which has been pulled from the database. I am not sure if I have written the str_replace correctly though as its not working .

```
$name = $row->leadname;
$body = str_replace('{name}, $name, $body);
```

e.g - if $name = fred the above is supposed to pull {name} out of $body and replace it with fred.

Comment: You are missing a single quote: $body = str_replace('{name}', $name, $body);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget a quote?

```
$name = $row->leadname;
$body = str_replace('{name}', $name, $body);
```